# itextsharp(xmlworker) parsing is slow

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, itext

I have been using iTextSharp for converting a MVC view to pdf .the view uses inline styling. Everything works fine with below code **but the parsing is slow**-

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 1, 0,0))
            {


                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();

                 XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer,doc, htmlcontent);
                //Above line is too slow    
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
```

as suggested by the experts here I moved on to below modifications-

- registering fonts
- Moved stylinging to diffrent css file

Now i am using the below code but the **generated pdf is blank**. it does retain the style but no fonts and **even this approach takes same time to parse**

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 1, 0,0))
                {
                    using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                    {

                        doc.Open();

                        // css 
                        var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
                        var cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS((new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Content/scptpdf.css"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)));
                        cssResolver.AddCss(cssFile);

                        // html
                        var fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
                        fontProvider.Register(Server.MapPath("~/Content/fonts/arial.ttf"));
                        fontProvider.Register(Server.MapPath("~/Content/fonts/arialbd."));
                        fontProvider.AddFontSubstitute("calibri","ARIAL");

                        var cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
                        var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
                        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

                        var pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer);
                        var html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
                        var css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

                        var worker = new XMLWorker(css,true);
                        var p = new XMLParser(worker);

                        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pdftext);
                        var htmlstream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                        p.Parse(htmlstream);

                        //XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, htmlcontent);

                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
```

I need to over the latency. Can some help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to comment on this question without seeing the HTML. Maybe you have huge tables with plenty of nested elements. Without the HTML it is also impossible to find out why your PDF is blank when you change your code. My first guess would be: you have a font issue, but that's only a guess.

Comment: I have been using itextsharp for two years. I liked it because it get things done but I had this same issue when I tried to convert a 100000 characters HTML file. iTextsharp converts it in ~10 minutes which is unacceptable. I tried to convert the same HTML file with wkhtmltopdf and I was surprised that it has converted the file in ~10 seconds. iTextSharp is a great tool but the performance is slow because it was written in a managed code. On the other hand, wkhtmltopdf is written entirely native. I use TuesPechkin which is the best wkhtmltopdf wrapper so far for ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the font types. Now iTEXT sharp uses its OWN . Its fast too.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. Can you please post the updated code?

Comment: Can you add the code that's working well for you please